# How much oil you can get from a dead animal

Tags: zoology

This is purely speculative, but is there a formula to calculate how much oil you can get from 1 Kg of biomass? 
I've seen bioreactors in farms where they put dung, vegetable scraps, and all bio scraps, where bacteria transformed the biomass in methane gas which then was used in powering electric generators or cooking stoves.

Comment: Well as I checked the internet and noone has done this experiment. So, it is a bit hard to answer it.

Comment: Oil is not biogas. what do you mean?

Comment: I was interested to know (at some point) how many dinosaurs had to die to create 1 kg of oil. I am aware that the oil deposits were formed by other type of organism not dinosaurs, but I was curious to know what mass of biological organisms needs to create 1 Kg of oil.
I wanted to be able to tell "You know, you just burned 1 TRex driving here."